# Nondecreasing converging sequences without the LEM

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, logic, intuitionistic-logic

A classical exercise for beginners in calculus is the following : let $(u_n)$ be a nondecreasing sequence of reals that converges to $0$. Show that $u_n\leq 0$ for all $n$.

There is a variation of course : replace "nondecreasing" by "increasing" and $\leq$ by $<$.

For the purposes of the question, it's important to note that my definition of converging here is $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N},\forall n\geq N, -\epsilon < u_n < \epsilon$. It's the standard definition but I avoided the use of the absolute value because it cannot be defined without the law of excluded middle.

The classical proof for this either starts with "assume $u_n>0$ (resp. $u_n\geq 0$), then blabla", or if you want to use the LEM later you can fix $n$ and pick $N\geq n$ such that $u_N< |u_n|$ after having dealt with the case where $u_n=0$.

But in those two proofs one really uses the law of excluded middle, perhaps multiple times. Moreover I'm having a hard time finding a proof that doesn't use the LEM. Heuristically, one could say that it's not possible to decide whether $u_n=0$ or not so it's not possible to find $N$ such that $-|u_n| < u_N < |u_n|$ and so to perform the argument.

So my question is natural

> Is it possible to prove either of the variants of the above exercise intuitionistically ?

To be clearer on what I mean (since the reals have different models intuitionistically), let me say that any specific intuitionistic model of the reals you like will be fine.

Comment: Absolute value is definable without LEM. e.g. as $max(x,-x)$. Probably better not using absolute value in the definition anyway.

Comment: @Potato44 : how is $\max$ defined without the LEM ?

Comment: Theorem 11.2.8 of the [HoTT Book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) mentions it is possible, but doesn't give the explicit construction. My guess (for Dedekind reals) is you union the lower sets and intersect the upper sets.

Comment: @Potato44 : If it's in HoTT then you're probably right, but that's odd because $|-|$ is nondifferentiable : whatever happened to the consistency of "every function is differentiable" ? (I must be missing something)

Comment: It's every function being continuous that is consistent. I've never heard of anyone using a similar statement with differentiability.

Comment: @Potato44 : in synthetic differential geometry, every function is differentiable but it's probably not the same model for the reals  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmhd8clDd_Y  right after 26:35)

Comment: Since LEM is fundamental and is the core in this question. Would you mind explaining it? Do you mean for any real numbers $a$, $b$, exactly one of the following is true: $a<b$, $a>b$, $a=b$?

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan this is a consequence of the LEM; the LEM itself is the following logical principle : for any proposition $P$, $P\lor \neg P$ ("$P$ or not $P$") holds; i.e. $P$ holds or $\neg P$ holds. Note that the instance you mention is enough to prove the result in question

Comment: Without LEM, we do not know whether the real number system $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeugChan : it can, in many different ways, that's what I mention at the end of my question; any model of the reals is fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $\epsilon=1/2$, we have that for all sufficiently large $n$, $u_n<1/2$.  Therefore, because the $u$’s are non-increasing, for all $n$, $u_n<1/2$.  Similarly for all positive integer $n$ and $k$, $u_n < 1/k$.  Therefore, by the definition of $\le$ (as in the HoTT book or Bishop & Bridges or any other source for basic constructive definitions), for all $n$, $u_n\le 0$.

If the $u$’s are increasing, then $u_n < u_{n+1} \le 0$, so $u_n < 0$.

Comment: Could you add a more precise reference to HoTT (or anythin else if you prefer) ? Which model of the reals are you referring to (for such a definition of $\leq$ it's probably the Dedekind reals ?) ?

Comment: The question was deliberately agnostic on the model of the reals, so I will keep the answer equally agnostic.

Comment: indeed it was, but is it the case that this is the definition of $\leq$ for any model ? This seems "unreasonable" for the Cauchy reals for instance (but I may very well be wrong!)

Comment: You can define $r\le s$ for the Cauchy reals as $\forall k\ r<s+1/k$, or as $\neg(r>s)$ or in terms of the Cauchy sequences; all are equivalent.

Comment: Oh, well it seems I was wrong, thank you !